# Visual Studio Borland dll error

Tags: database, visual-studio-2012, interbase

hen I run the application within Visual Studio 2012, it works like a charm,  but when I try to run the .exe file in the bin folder,  I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly       'Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a91a7c5705831a4f' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a91a7c5705831a4f'
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
at Borland.Data.TClassRegistryPackageItem..ctor(String PackageName)
at Borland.Data.TClassRegistry.RegisterPackageClass(String ClassName, String PackageName)
at Borland.Data.Units.DBXCommon.RegisterClassLoader(TDBXProperties DriverProperties, String ClassNameProp, String ClassNameDefault, String PackageNameProp, String PackageDefault, String& ResultPackageName)
at Borland.Data.TDBXDriverRegistry.GetDriver(TDBXDriverDef DriverDef)
at Borland.Data.TDBXConnectionFactory.GetDriver(String DriverName, TDBXProperties DriverProperties)
at Borland.Data.TDBXConnectionBuilder.CreateConnection()
at Borland.Data.TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection(TDBXContext DBXContext, TDBXProperties ConnectionProperties)
at Borland.Data.TAdoDbxConnection.Open()
at ProjectGroep9.LoginForm.connSuccess() in c:\Users\Tom\Project2TI\trunk\ProjectGroep9\ProjectGroep9\LoginForm.cs:line 146
at ProjectGroep9.LoginForm.bevestigLabel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Tom\Project2TI\trunk\ProjectGroep9\ProjectGroep9\LoginForm.cs:line 58
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value     [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

UPDATE: Visual studio, when throwing the error says:
    can't load assembly Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
    PublicKeyToken=a91a7c5705831a4f    or one of its dependencies.

A PowerShell command gives me following output for the.dll in the interbaseAdo.NETDriver program files folder:

```
Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   
PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
```

Comment: Me and my colleague are experiencing the same kind of problem, please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21628601/ado-net-2-0-interbase-driver-and-asp-net-wrong-assembly-reference, could you please find out what the PublicKeyToken of the Borland.Data.BdxCommonDriver.DLL on your system is?

Comment: Could you provide a few more details?

Like, are the referenced DLL files still within the bin folder?

Comment: Thanx for the comments guys, I did look into it today with my teachers at school, and their reaction was  something like "what the hell, embarcadero?"  ^^    the referenced files are in the bin folder :)

Comment: RFerwerda, maybe you can try this:  http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devcommon/deployingadodbxclient_xml.html

I am too novice for it (  can't even find the Public key Token)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Embarcadero RAD Studio installed (I use Delphi XE2 for example), it turns out that their dbExpress drivers are **newer** than the ones Embarcadero provided with their ADO.NET 2.0 drivers.

So in order to solve your particular issue, you might best change the app.config file in your Visual Studio solution to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <startup> 
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
   </startup>

   <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>      
      <remove invariant="Borland.Data.AdoDbxClient" />
      <add name="AdoDbx Data Provider" invariant="Borland.Data.AdoDbxClient"   
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for dbExpress Drivers" 
           type="Borland.Data.TAdoDbxProviderFactory, Borland.Data.AdoDbxClient, 
           Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b"/>
      <remove invariant="Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver" />
      <add name="Datasnap AdoDbx Data Provider" invariant="Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver" 
           description=".Net Framework Data Provider for Datasnap"   
           type="Borland.Data.TAdoDbxDatasnapProviderFactory, 
           Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
           PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b"/>      
    </DbProviderFactories>
   </system.data>  
</configuration>
```

After doing so, there is one minor detail that needs to be performed. You will have to find the location of the dbExpress configuration files called **'dbxdrivers.ini'** and **'dbxconnections.ini'**. If you place them in the exact same location of your binary executables, it will work. These drivers point to the correct assemblies from Embarcadero.

There is also a bug with setting up a connection to the database, which you may fix by the following workaround. You could lookup all provided dbProviderFactories (ie. the installed drivers) just to make sure your dbExpress drivers are installed correctly. The following method has it built in (just quick and dirty though):

```
public InterbaseTest()
{
  if (null == this.Connection)
  {
    try
    {
       /* First list all installed and registered DbProviderFactories */
      System.Data.DataTable dt = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();
      for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i.ToString(), dt.Rows[i][2].ToString());

       Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------\n");


       this.Connection = new TAdoDbxConnection(
         string.Format("DriverName=Interbase;Database={0};", this.DatabasePath) +
         "RoleName=RoleName;User_Name=sysdba;"+
         "Password=masterkey;SQLDialect=3" +                            
         "MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory," +
         "Borland.Data.DbxReadOnlyMetaData,Version=11.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral," +
         "PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b;GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverINTERBASE;" +
         "LibraryName=dbxint30.dll;VendorLib=GDS32.DLL"
       );
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

It may seem obvious that this.Connection is of type dbConnection, which is a field in this C# class.

Hope it helps!

UPDATE

Without Embarcadero RAD Studio installed, it may be the case that you lack the .ini files.
The contents are very straightforward, so you may create these files yourself.

The **'dbxconnections.ini'** should contain this:

```
[IBConnection]
;DelegateConnection=DBXTraceConnection
DriverName=Interbase
Database=database.gdb
RoleName=RoleName
User_Name=sysdba
Password=masterkey
ServerCharSet=
SQLDialect=3
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
BlobSize=-1
CommitRetain=False
WaitOnLocks=True
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
Trim Char=False
```

The contents of the **'dbxdrivers.ini'** file (the most important one) should contain:

```
[Installed Drivers]
DBXTrace=1
DBXPool=1
Interbase=1
MySQL=1 

[DBXPool]
DelegateDriver=True
DriverName=DBXPool
DriverUnit=Data.DBXPool
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXPoolDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver160.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXPoolDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b

[DBXTrace]
DelegateDriver=True
DriverName=DBXTrace
DriverUnit=Data.DBXTrace
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXTraceDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver160.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXTraceDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b

[AutoCommit]
False=0
True=1

[BlockingMode]
False=0
True=1

[WaitOnLocks]
False=1
True=0

[CommitRetain]
False=0
True=1

[OS Authentication]
False=0
True=1

[Multiple Transaction]
False=0
True=1

[Trim Char]
False=0
True=1

[SQLDialect]
1=0
2=1
3=2


[Interbase]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXInterBase
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver160.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxInterBaseDriver160.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxInterBaseDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverINTERBASE
LibraryName=dbxint.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlib.dylib
VendorLib=GDS32.DLL
VendorLibWin64=ibclient64.dll
VendorLibOsx=libgds.dylib
BlobSize=-1
CommitRetain=False
Database=database.gdb
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
Password=masterkey
RoleName=RoleName
ServerCharSet=
SQLDialect=3
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
User_Name=sysdba
WaitOnLocks=True
Trim Char=False

[Interbase TransIsolation]
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[MYSQL]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXMySQL
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver160.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMySqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMySQLDriver160.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMySqlMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxMySQLDriver,Version=16.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMYSQL
LibraryName=dbxmys.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlmys.dylib
VendorLib=LIBMYSQL.dll
VendorLibWin64=libmysql.dll
VendorLibOsx=libmysqlclient.dylib
BlobSize=-1
Database=DBNAME
ErrorResourceFile=
HostName=ServerName
LocaleCode=0000
Password=password
User_Name=user
Compressed=False
Encrypted=False
```

If you include these .ini files within your application folder where your binary is located, stuff should work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I don't have RAD studio though ( a tad expensive :D )  I'll give this solution a try after my exams, womewhere next month! :)

Comment: No problem, without RAD studio it might be harder to find out where the differences are, but the best try is still to include the .ini files. If you miss them, I can tell you the contents of these files (they are quite small). Just drop a note than. Good luck with your exams!

Comment: I just updated my answer with the contents of the ini files. I have tested this with my own binary and it works when including these two ini files within your binary folder.